# Vary the command/pathmap run in a rake rule based on which target is running

Tags: ruby, rake

I'm trying to write a Rakefile that both builds my code normally when I run `rake compile` but puts the targets in a different directory and builds with `-DTEST` when I run `rake test`.  I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do it, though.  I've got something like this at the moment:

```
SRC = FileList['src/*.erl']
OBJ = SRC.pathmap("%{src,ebin}/X.beam")

rule ".beam" => ["%{ebin,src}X.erl"] do |t|
  sh "erlc ... -o ebin #{t.source}"
end

task :compile => OBJ
```

What I'd like is a `task :test` that put the compiler output into `ebin_test` (basically changed all instances of `ebin` into `ebin_test` in the above code) and added a -DTEST to the `sh` call.  Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that wasn't a positive first question... no answers.

For the record, I solved the problem by having a task for both build and test that defined the compilation rules differently, and then had the public task call that task before doing the actual build/test run.  A couple of scoping issues, but nothing exciting.  I won't bother pasting the full resulting rakefile, but let me know if you're interested in taking a look.

Comment: Hey @womble, I am stuck in a similar situation. Would you mind posting the fixed up Rakefile here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your output directory depending on whether you want a release or
test build but you can't substitute that variable in FileList pathmap syntax.

So use ##map to map sources to objects and a proc to convert sources back to objects.

To select different builds I usually pass a variable to the rake command, like "rake CONFIG=Test build"

Here's a minimal rakefile which outputs to a single tree dependent on the CONFIG var:

```
## Config
CONFIG = ENV["CONFIG"] || "Release"
SRC_DIR = "src"
OBJ_DIR = File.join("obj",CONFIG)

## Tools
CC = "gcc"

## Inputs
C_SRCS = FileList["#{SRC_DIR}/**/*.c"]

## Outputs
# Map sources to objects
C_OBJS = C_SRCS.map { |f|
      f.sub(/^#{SRC_DIR}/, OBJ_DIR).ext('.o')
}

## Tasks
task :default => C_OBJS

# Generate a set of directory rules for the object files
C_OBJS.each do |f|
  directory f.pathmap('%d')
end

## Rules

# Generate objects from sources
rule '.o' => [
    proc { |tn| tn.sub(/#{OBJ_DIR}/, SRC_DIR).ext('.c') },
     '%d'
 ] do |t|
 sh %Q{#{CC} -c "#{t.source}" -o "#{t.name}"}
end
```

Note also the creation of the output directories.

More [notes and examples](http://markferry.net/Tech.RakeForMakeUsers) on my site.